# Do I need a multi-entry Schengen visa as an Indian if I’ve a layover in Germany on the way to UK and travelling to France post UK in the same trip?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany, schengen-visas, france

We'll be first arriving in London with a 1-hour layover in Munich and then taking a train from London to Paris. On return, we have a layover in Zurich and then back to India. The layovers are both 1 hour each.

This is our first time applying to both UK Visitor Visa and Schengen Visa. Which Schengen visa can we get? Would a single-entry Schengen visa suffice for the layover in Munich and entry in Paris? Or do we need multiple-entry? It would be really helpful for some clarity here.

I've heard that you can't get a multiple-entry
Schengen visa if it's your first time applying for the visa.

So, what should be done? Do we separately apply for a Germany Transit Visa (are we even eligible for this if we hold a Schengen visa)?

And is a transit marked as an entry for Schengen visa?
Please help. TIA!

Comment: "I've heard that you can't get a multiple-entry Schengen visa if it's your first time applying for the visa": it may be less likely to get s multiple-entry visa on a first application, but it's certainly not  impossible, notably if the applicant has an itinerary that requires one.

Comment: so the itinerary does require one or not?

Comment: Note that there are also "dual entry" visas.

Comment: On the way to London, I suppose both flights are on the same ticket?

Comment: yes, on the same ticket.

Answer (score 5):

A single entry visa should be adequate.  You do not need an airport transit visa if you hold a "regular" Schengen visa, but the transit does not count as an entry.  The trip from Paris to Zurich is entirely in the Schengen area, as you seem to be aware, so your only entry into the Schengen area will be during your trip from London to Paris.